# Jigoshop Styling Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, jigoshop

I am trying to get the jigoshop to put everything in my main container and it appears to be not working.

My template is below:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="productsidebar"><?php get_sidebar('products'); ?></div>
<div id="contentwrap">

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>

            <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>Pages:</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div><!-- #content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And i have this in my functions file as per Jigoshops themeing (http://forum.jigoshop.com/kb/customize-jigoshop/wrap-your-themes-content-for-jigoshop)

```
function mytheme_open_jigoshop_content_wrappers()
{
echo '<div id="productsidebar"></div><div id="contentwrap">';
}

function mytheme_close_jigoshop_content_wrappers()
{
echo '</div>';
}

function mytheme_prepare_jigoshop_wrappers()
{
remove_action( 'jigoshop_before_main_content', 'jigoshop_output_content_wrapper', 10 );
remove_action( 'jigoshop_after_main_content', 'jigoshop_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

add_action( 'jigoshop_before_main_content', 'mytheme_open_jigoshop_content_wrappers', 10 );
add_action( 'jigoshop_after_main_content', 'mytheme_close_jigoshop_content_wrappers', 10 );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mytheme_prepare_jigoshop_wrappers' );
```

It was obviously erroring when i put the sidebar function  in the functions file.

Can anyone advise how best to do this?

Site is http://upholstery180degree.co.uk/NewSite/

thanks

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the code your function is putting the product page in the main container as specified.

```
<div id="contentwrap">
    <ul class="products">
    <li class="product first">
```

Although from what it seems like you are using a different template for your shop page in which is causing it to show the widgets from you site.  Your code is working properly, I would go into your product page and change the type of template it is using and have it the same as your other pages.  Also you would not need the sidebar div information as it is not part of the main wrapper.

```
function mytheme_open_jigoshop_content_wrappers()
{
    echo '<div id="contentwrap">';
}

function mytheme_close_jigoshop_content_wrappers()
{
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Hi Roberto, i am using the default template? Ive just checked :S

Comment: All of your pages using the default template?  Something is calling the <?php get_sidebar(); ?> in your product page.  It is most likely a template or the page you are using.

Comment: ive just added two pages, of shop, the one in qusetion is the 1st option. As you can see its still sat outside it :S

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by sitting outside it?

Comment: Hi Robert, this is because im using my own theme, so i need to work it wrong what i have